# Success probability when we have expected return and volatility

Tags: probability, finance, volatility

I am reading Taleb ["Fooled By Randomness"](https://www.randomhousebooks.com/books/176225/), and the author says that a 15% return with 10% volatility translates to 93% success in a year and 50.02% success in any given second.

Could someone help me understand this calculation?

Comment: Is this a better fit for [Personal Finance & Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/)? I suspect [Quant](https://quant.stackexchange.com/) would close the question. Either way, this seems to be a matter of interpreting financial terminology more than statistics.

Comment: Using a 24 hour day and a 365.25 day year, I get 50.0007%, not 50.02%.  Maybe Taleb is assuming actual trading hours (6.5 hour days on the NYSE, for instance) and only business days, holidays removed, for which I get 50.002% (rounded up).  Maybe you or he overlooked a zero?  @Dave I hope this helps make it clear there is a definite statistical question here.  It amounts to knowing how the variance of Brownian Motion depends on time.

Comment: Cross-posted on Quantitative Finance SE [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/77609).

Answer (score 0):

If
$$
r \sim N(\mu=0.15,\Sigma=0.1^2) \\
$$
Then it's easy to see that
$$
P(r>0)\approx 0.931928
$$

No idea what "50.02% success in any given second" means, need more context.

Comment: It means that given volatility and return happens in any given second then probability of achieving expected return is 50.02%